# Encoding String values with base64

Tags: java, utf-8, base64

so I was working on a homework assignment for my CSC420 class. Professor wanted us to use java code to encrypt two string values that the user would enter. I was able to do, no real issue there; the main problem is that the sample output that he gave to us so that we would know if we got the "right answer" is somehow different then mine. I have attached my code below, my output, and his output; if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
package Homework;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8; 
import java.util.Base64; 
import java.util.Base64.Encoder; 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class HW4 { 
  public static String b64enc(String string) throws Exception { 

    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder(); 
    byte[] data = string.getBytes(UTF_8); 
    String encodedString = encoder.encodeToString(data); 

return encodedString; 
} 

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception { 

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter the first String: ");
      String string1 = scan1.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter the second string: ");
      String string2= scan1.nextLine();
      scan1.close();  
      String encodedString = b64enc(string1 + string2);
      System.out.println(encodedString);
    }
}
```

[image: Text[![]]][1](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

[image]

Comment: First, I was off with my first statement.  Second, I tried encoding `hellohi` as a direct input using your code and it works fine.  I then added the `Scanner` input and that works fine as well. I'm wondering if it might be an encoding issue at the OS level

Comment: How can hello+hi and hi+hello in the second screenshot produce the same base64 output? Did you ever check the base64 codes on https://www.base64decode.org/ ?

Comment: If you go the the [https://www.base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org) and enter your base64 encoded string there you'll see, that your encoding works correctly.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there really anything I can do at this point or should I just turn it in and see what the prof. has to say?

Comment: @Zethos, try emailing the TA/Professor. The second screenshot is definitely wrong.

Comment: @jps I haven't checked out that site yet and the second screenshot is my professor's output; mine works, I believe, in generally the same fashion just with a different encoded string being displayed.

Comment: @user85421 You are absolutely right, I accidentally wrote my problem down wrong here, so that you for point it out. The Strings that I refer to are a string of characters for a user to input: words or phrases.

Comment: @HarshalParekh I will do so shortly, just figured I could as some people here beforehand.

Comment: also not sure how the strings should be combined... the way its done now, there is no way to restore both strings since there is no separator (`"hi"+"hello"` produces same result as `"hihel" + "lo"`)

Comment: @user85421 Well, for this assignment we are only supposed to worry about encryption, hopefully, next class we will go over the homework and discuss how to restore and decrypt both string values.

Comment: @Zethos I've run your code both from the IDE and commanline on MacOS and I get the correct result (based on the output of your professor)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So are you saying it changes based on what OS its running off of?

Comment: @Zethos I can't verify it, but since your code is producing two different results, it's possible a character set issue try removing `UTF_8` from `getBytes` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: as I suspected, it is how the strings should be combined - please check your assignment, probably you did not read it properly - the strings should not be concatenated, but combined by some operation! (`UTF_8` (or `ASCII`) is correct (for given examples))

Comment: is it part of the assignment to find out HOW the strings are combined, that is, encrypted?

Comment: @user85421 Yeah, I must have missed it when he was talking about it; the assignment itself doesn't say anything about that; but he probably forgot to put that in there. The main idea of the assignment is to show that we can encrpyt soenmthing and that pretty much it. Just baby steps for now i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your prof's program has the same control value for 'hihello' and 'hellohi' is special; obviously, just Base64-encoding a string (which doesn't delete information; you can get back to the original with it; that is the point) implies it is impossible for 2 different inputs to generate the same output.

I conclude that you must not have read the instructions correctly. You're looking for an algorithm where entering the strings in a different order nevertheless produces the same 'encoded value' is explained. 'concatenate them and then base64 the result' wouldn't.

Comment: I believe that I read the assignment properly; all he stated was to create a code that would decrypt two string values that were given. I wil email him today to see if maybe what I have is truely fine or if I did, infact, misconstrue something he requested.

Comment: Yeah, If memory serves correctly, base64 is just the 64 characters from ASCII that can implemented in plaintext; right?

Comment: Yes, it maps 3 bytes (each byte can be any of 256 different options, for a total of 256*256*256 = 16777216 different options) onto 4 characters picked from a set of 64 options (a-z,A-Z,0-9 and 2 others, which ones depend a bit on which flavour of base64): 64*64*64*64  = 16777216. Which is why that works.

Answer (score 2):

I think I do understand the assignment now.

The code is supposed to encode one *message* string using another string as key. Base64 is used only for encoding the result since it is binary data and can (will) contain codes that are not printable - so the result is represented as text and, for example, can be mailed to the teacher.

First we note that the order of the strings does not matter, so there is no real distinction which is key, which is message.

Next we can decode the example results, for example using linux command `base64` (I used GIT Bash, but there are also online services available for this). I also piped the result to `od` (hex dump utility to see hexadecimal values):

```sh
$ echo "AAxMTE8=" | base64 -d | od -t x1 -c
```

which returns

> ```
> 0000000  00  0c  4c  4c  4f
>          \0  \f   L   L   O
> ```

Note that it is `5` bytes long, the same as the longer of the input string - so we can assume that the strings are not being concatenated, which would change the length, but that the bytes of each string are being combined in some way. Also that each character is using one byte, so encoding probably is `UTF-8` or even `ASCII`.

Further we see that the result ends with `"LLO"`, the uppercase version of the end of the longest input `"hello"` - looks like the position of the bytes were not changed, just the values combined by some operation. Lets consider some operations that can be used to combine the bytes:

- *Subtraction* or *division*: won't work since order of input does not matter;
- *Addition* or *multiplication*: not good because of possible overflow/underflow
- Bitwise *AND*, *NAND*, *OR* or *NOR*: won't work, information loss (e.g. `x AND 0` is always `0`)
- Bitwise *XOR* (exclusive OR): (almost) perfect, easy to encrypt, easy to decrypt, order does not matter (but not very strong)

Lets check what happens with *XOR*:

```
input1: "hello" == [ 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f ] // using ASCII/UTF-8
input2: "hi"    == [ 0x68, 0x69 ]                   // "
result: "∅∅LLO" == [ 0x00, 0x0c, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x4f ] // ∅ not printable

0x68 ^ 0x68 == 0x00  // correct!
0x65 ^ 0x69 == 0x0f  // "
0x6c ^  X   == 0x4c  // what is X?
0x6f ^  X   == 0x4f  // "
```

Now we just need to see what should happen with the last 3 bytes, one input is too short, that is, what is `X`. It is not hard find out that `0x6c ^ 0x20 == 0x4c` and `0x6f ^ 0x20 == 0x4f`, actually `A ^ X == B` implies that `A ^ B == X`. So we conclude that the smaller string must be filled up with 0x20 or the white-space character `' '`.

---

The algorithm must be something like: make both input strings the same size by appending white-spaces (`' '`) to the smaller string. Convert both inputs to byte array. Combine the bytes of each array using exclusive OR. Encode the result using Base64.

Comment: amazing, so the whole Q/A here boils down to *This is my professors answer, can someone explain what his question was?* ;-)

Comment: @jps Sorta I guess yeah, my main thing was wondering why my professor got a different output from me; I am new to the type of coding, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't screwing up somehow.